# How is the location of .ssh determined?

Tags: windows, ssh, git

On my windows machine, when I ran ssh-keygen, it created a directory at ~/.ssh with the key (and a known hosts file), and then I could use ssh to connect to sites (and git worked with ssh).

On my colleague's windows machine, ssh mysteriously created something in ~\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Git.ssh, and ssh output refers to it as /.ssh.

Any idea what the difference here would be? I assume there is a setting that determines where ssh will look for this, but I have not been able to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it might look for .ssh in the directory `HOME` points to. `HOME` isn't normally set under Windows, but you can set it manually.

Comment: what program did you use to create your keys? and what program did he use? What program are you using to connect to sites with those keys, and what program for using git with those keys? On windows, apps like to use different places (inconsistent convention). On Linux/Mac (and cygwin for windows) the default is in the .ssh folder in your home directory: ~/.ssh  (~ is a shortcut for your user's home directory on unix based OSes)

Comment: we both used the ssh-keygen that came with git. echristopherson was correct, though--I have a HOME variable and he doesn't (I'm sure I set that ages ago and forgot). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, I believe you are asking about the Git application not the .ssh file.

According to the documentation on Github it indicates that their stand alone application will set up .ssh keys for you *or* use your existing keys.

Based on what I have read, it seems to just be the default place that their application places the key. Placing an app-created ssh key in a unique location would prevent any interference with existing ssh keys as well as ones you may generate in the future.

As for where the default key store is for ssh, that would be dictated by your environmental parameters along with the /etc/ssh/ssh_config equivalent for your ssh application.